# Detect if string has a substring and delete element in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm just trying to detect whether a string has a substring in it so I can remove it. So I'm detecting words from posts and storing them into m. Then I want to loop through them to detect keywords. I can't get it to work though. The values 4-6 are just letters and numbers.

```
m = re.findall('some values from 4-6', submission.selftext)
print(m)
for x in m:
    i = 0
    if any("memory" or "hard" or "drive" in s for s in x):
        del m[i]
    i += 1
print(m)
```

But it seems that it doesn't work when I try to search x. It skips that if statement entirely no matter what m is.

Comment: `any("memory" in s or "hard" in s or "drive" in s for s in x)` is probably what you need.

Comment: Not sure why you iterate over `m`, and then iterate over `x` as well: `x` should be a string containing any of the words you're looking for. `If any("memory" in x or "hard" in x or "drive" in x):` seems more logical.

Comment: Adding in s after each didn't change the result. And I iterate over x because m can contain ['hard-drive', 'memory-card'] and if I just iterate over m, it will use the entire string rather than just the first element, x. Oh I see what you mean, I'll give that a try.

Comment: Why not do it directly in your regular expression?

Comment: I'm fairly new to python. I haven't done anything with it until recently. I'm still unfamiliar on what I can and can't do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

```
if any("memory" or "hard" or "drive" in s for s in x):
```

should be:

```
if any("memory" in s or "hard" in s or "drive" in s for s in x):
```

And you are skipping some `i`s:

The best way to fix this is by using a list comprehension:

```
m = [x for x in m if not ("memory" in x or "hard" in x or "drive" in x)]
```

You don't need to iterate through `x`, since each `s` would be a character, and would never contain the string `memory`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not completely clear. I am inferring:

- `'some values from 4-6'` is a regular expression containing groups, e.g. `"(memory)|(hard)|(drive)"`.
- `submission.selftext` is the text you are searching.

Then, `m` is a list of match objects, `x` is a match object, and `s` is one of the groups, i.e. a word. Correct?

In that case, the test you want is `s in ["memory", "hard", "drive"]`.

You can improve on this by changing the regular expression to `"memory|hard|drive"`. Then `m` is simply a list of words.

I second the suggestion to use a list comprehension:

```
m = [x for x in m if x not in ["memory", "hard", "drive"]]
```

Alternatively, use the `filter` function:

```
m = filter(lamda x: x not in ["memory", "hard", "drive"], m)
```